# sendmail not working on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, sendmail

Our websites aren't sending automated emails because the php_mail() functions does not work and it appears to be because sendmail wont work.

I have tried using various command lines but no email sends. I also have qmail installed. 
The php.ini shows that it is using sendmail.
There is nothing in the logs: `/var/log/maillog`

When I try to install sendmail again it states these errors:

```
Error: plesk-mail-qc-driver conflicts with plesk-mail-pc-driver-11.0.9-cos6.build110120608.16.x86_64
Error: plesk-mail-pc-driver conflicts with psa-qmail-rblsmtpd-0.88-cos6.build110120606.19.x86_64
Error: plesk-mail-pc-driver conflicts with plesk-mail-qc-driver-11.0.9-cos6.build110120608.16.x86_64
Error: plesk-mail-pc-driver conflicts with 2:psa-qmail-1.03-cos6.build110120606.19.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It does not recognize `--skip-broken`
`rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` results in no change

When I try to do `service sendmail start` it replies: 'sendmail: unrecognized service'

How can I get sendmail to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using rpm and centos packages on an Ubuntu machine. This is not going to work at all. On top of that you're using plesk, which is sort-of considered malware around here.

Comment: Thanks. I've sent my query to the Plesk Parrallels forum.